# Installed edubuntu from software center, but can't find it!

Tags: edubuntu

Using 12.04.1, installed Edubuntu from the software center. The software center says everything is installed, but the Search can't find any of the programs like Tux Math, Tux Paint, etc.
I'm used to 10.04 LTS, on which it was really easy to find all the Edubuntu software. Where is it on 12.04, hidden away somewhere?

Comment: You need to logout and select "Ednuntu" from the login screen to access it.  Did you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have installed "Educational desktop for Ubuntu"

Logout from you user account first.

Click on this icon

[image: a busy cat]

Then change to edubuntu. Below edubuntu is not there. But in your computer it will show.

[image: a busy cat]

Then login.